# SVN 1.7 reapply reverted changes

Tags: svn, merge, diff, patch

I have problem with applying svn patch. I'm using svn 1.7 with TortoiseSVN.

Some changes were made in revision A. There were some following commits until revision B reverted changes done in revision A. Then after some time there's need to reapply changes from revision A. How to make it so as not to lose information about moved files?

As for now I tried to create patch of revision A using TortoiseSVN -> Show log -> Show changes as unified diff. Then I checkout revision B applied this patch, but it failed to do the job. Some files were create/deleted instead of moved or moved then modified. Some were alos marked as locally deleted (at least from IntelliJ point of view).

How to reapply changes from rev A cleanly? Is it even possible with SVN? I would like avoid redoing all the changes manually as there're a couple of hundred affected files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because:

- In order to UNDO revision A you created reverse-merge revision B
- Revision B is ordinary revision

in order to UNDO UNDO you have to create reverse-merge (for revision B) revision C

PS: this way your log will be not-readable without drink very soon